# How to use the Version Class in a LINQ query on latest release folder

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

We are doing software builds and storing them in folders in a pre-release folder in a four digit Major.Minor.Build.rev (0.0.0.0) format.

1. I was wondering if there is a way to use the Version Class in a LINQ query?
2. Would there be any benefit using a LINQ query or should I stick with the non-LINQ query code?

Here is the code I have currently:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string latest = GetLatestBuildVersion(@"\\path\to\network\folder");
    latest = "";
}

static string GetLatestBuildVersion(string sPath)
{
    Version latestVersion = new Version();
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(sPath);
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        string subfolderNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(dir);
        try
        {
            Version subfolderVersion = new Version(subfolderNameOnly);
            if (latestVersion.CompareTo(subfolderVersion) < 0)
            {
                latestVersion = subfolderVersion;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Just continue
        }
    }
    return latestVersion.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you already have code that works, it seems like you should probably just stick with it. Any gained advantage would be pretty small.

Comment: It does work. I was hoping to doing it in less code. I have some code where I can get up to a point with the query, but I get stuck on the Path.GetFileName and the second instantiation of version class for subfolderversion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect task for chained LINQ methods:

```
static string GetLatestBuildVersion(string sPath)
{
    return Directory.GetDirectories(sPath)
        .Select(v => new Version(Path.GetFileName(v)))
        .OrderBy(v => v)
        .Last();
}
```

Add error handling as needed (given the particular context, I'd rather let it blow up, than have it run on files which are not what/where I expect them to be)